Docxtemplater - using multiple filters | Country-specific format and custom decimals
Is there a way to apply multiple filters in docxtemplater?
I would like to apply a "toLocaleNumber" filter as well as a "toFixed" filter.
Example:
Input for variable 'Price': 500.50
In the document it says "EUR {price | toLocaleNumber: 'de-de'}"
and the output would be "EUR 500,5".
It's obviously missing the last 0. If the input was 500, I would also like to show two decimals to have 500,00. I found the toFixed function that would take care of it, but I'm not sure how to combine two filters on the same variable.
Any ideas?
Many thanks,
Jenny

Not sure how helpful (or new) this is for anyone, but just in case I would like to share my solution.
Within our toLocaleNumber function we use toLocaleString(locale). I first tried adding a step before that and applied the toFixed function to the original number input, missing the fact that that function returns a string which then of course causes toLocaleString to throw an error.
I then found that toLocaleString already has an option parameter called "minimumFractionDigits", which nicely adds two trailing zeros even if the input number doesn't have any decimals.
